# Angular CDK - Attach portal into projected content

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I am building a master-detail component in Angular. This component allows for custom listitem templates and custom selected item templates for displaying the selected item.

Depending on the route of the application, a different component is used for the master-detail component.

Some of the content is projected using `ng-template`, directives and `ContentChild` queries.

I have this StackBlitz link to simulate the scenario: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-di4q3k?file=app%2Fprojection.component.ts

I want the contents of `ProjectionToProjectComponent` to be visible. If I have a look at the `PortalHost` while debugging, the `ComponentPortal` is attached to the host, but it is not rendered in the DOM:

[image]

Can someone help me out with this or is this a bug?